# What happens to the current Search crawl when the timeout is reached?

Tags: search, crawling, schedule

I've got a question and can't find a answer on Technet.

We have search crawls setup to repeat within the day. The configuration looks like this:

[image]

My question is:
Basically, that means that the incremental should start at 1AM , repeat every 7 minutes and then finish at 11PM that same night. What happens when a incremental starts at 9PM that night, but takes a long time and runs over the 11PM 'deadline'. Does that Incremental Restart at 1AM, or does it continue where it was paused at 11PM?

To me, it does seem like it continues after 1AM.
I had a incremental start at 3:40PM and then it ran for 13 hours and finished at 5AM the next morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the long-running incremental crawl finishes after the 11 PM deadline, the next incremental crawl (e.g. at 1 AM) will be a new incremental crawl. The long running crawl will finish its work and the new crawl will process all the changes from the content database since the long-running crawl started.

Comment: Thanks, but not really answering the question...

Comment: Sure it does, unless we don't understand your question. If an incremental is missed, it starts right after the previous crawl ends. This is part of the reason they implemented Continuous Crawling in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Tx Thomas. Makes much more sense now :-) Appreciated